# Unity C# Trig Functions in movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I'm creating an fps game in unity and chose to not use the included First Person Controller script to reduce complexity. The camera object will constantly be set to the players position and can rotate. I have created a script containing the following code for movement:

```
float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

Vector2 rotation = new Vector2(
    Mathf.Cos(cam.transform.eulerAngles.y * deg2rad), (Mathf.Sin(cam.transform.eulerAngles.y * deg2rad))
);

rb.velocity = (
    new Vector3(
        (-rotation.x * h * speed) + (rotation.y * v * speed),
        rb.velocity.y,
        (-rotation.y * h * speed) + (-rotation.x * v * speed)
    )
);
```

When I test out the game, the movement is correct along the x-axis in both directions, but is unusual when the players y rotation becomes something other than being aligned with the x-axis (Like moving the player backwards will actually move them forwards and visa-versa).

I'm open to an alternative besides using trig functions for the movement, as I have already used transform.forward and transform.right, but they didn't work entirely.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd say is that unless you're intending to learn trig and geometrical functions then you should not reinvent the wheel.  As you've stated you want to create a FPS game so really you should leverage the scripts and prefabs that others have created to enable the creation of your game.

If you don't want to use the inbuilt FPS Controller script I'd recommend using a free Asset package named '3rdPerson+Fly'.  It appears a bit complex at first however you'll learn about states and stackable behaviours/modes which is going to get you an outcome much faster than creating from scratch.  You'll also get the flexibility and openness that comes with a non-inbuilt package.  This way you can peek at the inner workings if desired or simply build on top of them.  Don't fall for NIH (Not Invented Here) syndrome and stand on the shoulders of giants instead :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is likely caused by the fact that sin and cos can't determine by themselves which "quadrant" they're in. For example 30 degree angle is the same as a 150 degree angle as far as Sin is concerned.

This video is a fast and good explanation of the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=736Wkg8uxA8

Comment: I've attached a Debug.Log() statement to print out the cos and sin of the angle, and none come out the same, they [appear](https://imgur.com/a/bvuAlZ1) to be returning a number set unique to that quadrant. You can see (-) numbers in the x.